# im getting product in views.py but it is empty in template. it is empty

Tags: parameters, django-templates

this is my product.html template

```
{% block title %}
{% load static %}
{{ product.product_name }} 
{% endblock %}
```

this is my views.py

```
def productview(request, myid):
    viewed_Product=Product.objects.filter(id=myid)
    print(viewed_Product)
    return render(request, 'shop/product.html',{'product' : viewed_Product})
```

this is my models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id=models.AutoField
    product_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    desc=models.CharField(max_length=350,default='')
    pub_date=models.DateField()
    price=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this since .filter returns a list so you need to senf the 0th index of viewed_product[0] in render

```
 def productview(request, myid):
        viewed_Product=Product.objects.filter(id=myid)
        print(viewed_Product)
        return render(request, 'shop/product.html',{'product' : viewed_Product[0]})
```